# Order by joined table through table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

my mySQL (pun intended) is a bit rusty. I am trying to join a table through another table.

```
carparks has many clients
clients has many cars
```

This is the query

```
select `carparks`.* from `carparks`

left join `clients` on `carparks`.`carpark_id` = `clients`.`carpark_id` 

left join `cars` on `clients`.`client_id` = `cars`.`client_id` 

where `carparks`.`carpark_id` in (1, 3, 8, 33, 34, 38, 39) 

order by `cars`.`created_at` desc
```

As you can see I am trying to order by the created_at column of cars, the above query though returns duplicated carparks for each of the cars within the carpark.

What I am looking at is to return only those carparks with the ids in the WHERE IN clause, simply ordered by the created_at column of the cars table.

Thanks

Comment: add GROUP BY clause

Comment: The requirements are ill-defined. A carpark can have many cars. Assume carpark A has a car created in 2016 and carpark B has two cars - one created in 2015 and one in 2017. Which should come first?

Comment: @Mureinik Carpark B would come first as it has the most recent created_at timestamp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aggregation in your order  by clause on max created date from cars table

```
SELECT cp.* 
FROM `carparks` cp
LEFT JOIN `clients` cl ON cp.`carpark_id` = cl.`carpark_id` 
LEFT JOIN `cars` c ON cl.`client_id` = c.`client_id` 
WHERE cp.`carpark_id` IN (1, 3, 8, 33, 34, 38, 39) 
GROUP BY cp.`carpark_id`
ORDER BY MAX(c.`created_at`) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for this one, I haven't thought about using MAX, does it have any performance impact?

Comment: @0plus1 for better performance idea you can run EXPLAIN plan for your with order by max and without max

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the wanted dates to one per carpark before joining back to carparks. Note if a carpark does have no cars than a left join is logical, however I expect every carpark (that is open for business) will have cars, so that left join might not be needed.

```
SELECT `carparks`.*
FROM `carparks`
LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT
              `carparks`.`carpark_id`
            , max(`cars`.`created_at`) max_car_created
       FROM `clients`
       INNER JOIN `cars` ON `clients`.`client_id` = `cars`.`client_id`
       GROUP BY 
              `carparks`.`carpark_id`
       ) d ON `carparks`.`carpark_id` = d.`carpark_id`
WHERE `carparks`.`carpark_id` IN (1, 3, 8, 33, 34, 38, 39)
ORDER BY max_car_created DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the number of carparks and clients before doing the joins, this will reduce the execution time of the query.

```
SELECT A.* FROM (SELECT * FROM `carparks` WHERE `carpark_id` in
(1, 3, 8, 33, 34, 38, 39)) A LEFT JOIN
(SELECT `carpark_id`, `client_id` FROM `clients` WHERE `carpark_id` 
in (1, 3, 8, 33, 34, 38, 39)) B ON A.`carpark_id`=B.`carpark_id` LEFT JOIN
`cars` C ON B.`client_id` = C.`client_id`
GROUP BY A.`carpark_id`
ORDER BY MAX(C.`created_at`) DESC
```